# Background image is not set properly in ios devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vite

Recently I have been contributing to a website, However I am getting an issue in IOS mobile devices wrt to bg Images The images a kind of zoomed when i see it on IOS mobile device , and it is perfect for desktop, Android, And responsive console in Developer Tools (Inspect ). I need help to make it properly set the Images are give below

[Devloper console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x8KJ.png) image

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x8KJ.png)

The below Image Is on actual mobile device which is the issue i am facing with bg images.
[IOS Mobile phone bg image which is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLCQt.jpg)%5D(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLCQt.jpg)

This next image is desktop view:
[Destop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QomQ.jpg)%5D(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QomQ.jpg)
below is the code we are using for that image:

```
.bg-pronight {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 200vh;
    background-image: url('../assets/pronighthpimg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
.headingpronight{
    font-size: 8vw;
    margin: 0px;
}
#aboutus{
    padding: 0.5% 0%;
    /* margin-top: 3.5rem; */
}
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
    .headingpronight{
        font-size: 14vw;
    }
    .bg-pronight{
        background-position: center;
        background-size: auto;
    }
}
```

I did tried some Stackover flow question and anser but didn't worked out.  I need help to fix that image zoom on IOS mobile device Thank you.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed` is, and has been for a long while, broken on iOS. There isn't a great solution for it except making your element fixed, but that solution on works so much. The best way might just be to detect iOS and set your attachment to `scroll`, which might not look great, but at least doesn't look _terrible_.

Comment: Put the background on a pseudo element and position that fixed.

Comment: Not working @somethinghere

Comment: Okay, that's not true because `scroll` is the default. _I did not say your background was going to be nicely fixed_, I said that isn't really _possible_ on iOS. @AHaworth has a decent solution you could try. Please read the comment and provide more constructive feedback than "not working".

Comment: thank you guys its better then before @somethinghere @A Haworth